# AWS fargate task throwing Asm fetching username: AuthorizationData is malformed, empty field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager

I want to run fargate task with an image in a private registry.This registry will use access token for authentication. I created secret with key access_token and value as the token .Also I tried by adding another key token_type and value bearer .But both approaches are throwing Asm fetching username: AuthorizationData is malformed, empty field.Can anyone help ? I think the way I am saving my secret is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing exactly the same thing and getting the same error. I tried using full username and password. Didnt work. I will post if I find anythingLet me know if it works for you :)

Followed the steps mentioned in the below URL:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html

But no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just add field "username" in your secret.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).